# how to display records to 2 listview in c# from sql database?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I would like to display the record from database to c# in listview. When I display the record into 2 different listview, the record in the second listview does not appear.

In listview1, i would like to display the record where package = textbox4.text, then in listview2, i would like to display the record where package = textbox5.text.

Here is my line of code, only the records in first listview display.

Please help me. Thank you

```
//code for first listview
MySqlConnection.Open();
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from reservation_inventory where package='"+textBox4.Text+"'", MySqlConnection);

p_table.Clear();
SqlDataAdapter m_da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from reservation_inventory where package='" + textBox4.Text + "'", MySqlConnection);

m_da.Fill(p_table);
listView1.Items.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < p_table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow drow = p_table.Rows[i];

    if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["id"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["equipment"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["status"].ToString());
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}

// code for second listview
SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("Select * from reservation_inventory where package='" + textBox5.Text + "'", MySqlConnection);

p_table.Clear();
SqlDataAdapter m_da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from reservation_inventory where package='" + textBox5.Text + "'", MySqlConnection);

m_da.Fill(p_table);
listView2.Items.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < p_table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow drow = p_table.Rows[i];

    if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["id"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["equipment"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["status"].ToString());
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

Comment: why loop the objects making list view items... just go `listView2.DataSource = p_table; listView2.DataBind();`

Answer (score 2):

In your second loop change

```
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

to

```
listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
```